# set Facebook image as button background

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

So I have the following

```
let profilepicURl = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(user_id_fb)/picture?type=large" //user_id_fb like 1251246454544 your facebook ID
```

but what I am wanting to do is put that url image where the following image is I thought I could use import Kingfisher since I already have that integrated with the app, but I am unsure how to achieve what I am seeking.

```
// Image needs to be added to project.
         let buttonIcon = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")

        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.checkLogin(_:)))
         rightBarButton.image = buttonIcon

          self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

I have tried the following

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.checkLogin(_:)))
                    rightBarButton.kf.setImage(with: facebookProfileUrl, for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: [.imageModifier(modifier)], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                    //rightBarButton.image = buttonIcon

                      self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

but it returns

> Use of unresolved identifier 'modifier'

Comment: rightBarButton.kf.setImage(with: url)

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com I have set that by  let facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(fbID)/picture?type=large"

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com commented on your answer seems an issue now with .kf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom button and set it to UIBarButton and set the image to button.

```
  let button = UIButton()
  button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 51, height: 31) //set the frame
  let modifier = AnyImageModifier { return $0.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) }
  button.kf.setImage(with: url, for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: [.imageModifier(modifier)], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
  button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("yourActionFunc"), for: .touchUpInside)

  let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
  barButton.customView = button
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: then I get Value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' has no member 'kf'